# resize widget in kivy scatter

Tags: python, kivy, scatter

I want to use kivy scatter in order to resize the widgets which scatter contains. So, I created `box_total` contained in `scatter`, contained in `floatlayout`.

This is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text = 'something')
        b.add_widget(button)


        box_labels = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')
        label1 = Label(text = 'hello')
        box_labels.add_widget(label1)
        label2 = Label(text = 'world')
        box_labels.add_widget(label2)

        box_buttons = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')
        button1 = Button(text = 'hello')
        box_buttons.add_widget(button1)
        button2 = Button(text = 'world')
        box_buttons.add_widget(button2)

        box_total = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        box_total.add_widget(box_labels)
        box_total.add_widget(box_buttons)


        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        f.add_widget(s)        
        s.add_widget(box_total)
        b.add_widget(f)

        return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

How can I resize the inner widget `box_total` in order to occupy the whole `FloatLayout` area? (the bottom half of the window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scatter` isn't a layout, therefore the automatical setting of the position won't work here. Use `ScatterLayout` to behava like both a `Scatter` and a `FloatLayout`.

```
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
ScatterLayout()
```

Or do that manually with setting the positions of the widgets inside the `FloatLayout`, but remember you'll need to do `size_hint=(None, None)` first.